# Javascript Fetch API: header params not working

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

This is my sample request:

```
var header = new Headers({
  'Platform-Version': 1,
  'App-Version': 1,
  'Platform': 'FrontEnd'
});

var myInit = {
  method : 'GET',
  headers: header,
  mode   : 'no-cors',
  cache  : 'default'
}

fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/front_end/v1/login', myInit)
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res.text())
  })
```

When I debug, I see that this request is sent successfully to server, but server hasn't received header params (in this case is `Platform-Version`, `App-Version` and `Platform`). Please tell me which part do I config wrong.

thanks

Comment: Can you explain in detail please. I follow on this guide: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch (Header section)

Comment: Does your browser fully support Fetch / Headers API?

Comment: I think so. I'm using latest version of Chrome on Mac.

Comment: Using the Chrome developers tools, does the network request include the headers?

Comment: oh. no. So I think something is wrong in my code.

Comment: I have checked api doc and I think I have used correctly :-?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using it correctly, but you have to tell your backend service to allow custom headers (`X-`). For example, in PHP:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With");
```

Also, your custom headers should be prefixed with `X-`. So you should have:

```
'X-Platform-Version': '1'
```

And one last thing, your `mode` needs to be `cors`.

You can see that standard headers are being sent with the following code. take a look at the network tab to see the standard request headers.

```
var header = new Headers();

// Your server does not currently allow this one
header.append('X-Platform-Version', 1);

// You will see this one in the log in the network tab
header.append("Content-Type", "text/plain");

var myInit = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: header,
    mode: 'cors',
    cache: 'default'
}

fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/front_end/v1/login', myInit)
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res.text())
    });
```

Comment: I have set that option on server (I'm using rails), but no work. Moreover, I think request header that I saw in chrome doesn't depend on server (because it has been sent before come server).

Comment: @TrầnKimDự, I did some more testing on this, try changing the mode of the request to either `cors`, or `same-origin`. When I change it to either one of those, I can see the headers in the network tab in Chrome.

Comment: thanks so much. changing from "no-cors" to "cors" works for me. Also I need to do 2 things: 1. change on server (as your answer) 2. change from "no-cors" to "cors".