# Request header are not filled using Fetch API

Tags: javascript, fetch

I am experimenting a things that I don't understand. When I try to set headers of a request using the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), no headers are actually defined.

Here is a piece of code and a link to a fiddle to be able to reproduce.

```
function createRequest(type, url, payload) {
  const options = { headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "x-request-id": '...',
    "x-sender-id": "mysender"
  },
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify(payload),
  mode: 'no-cors',
  cache: 'no-cache'
  };
  return new Request(url, options);
}

// -----------------------------
// a simple test
const request = createRequest('post', '/check', {test: 'where are my headers?'});
```

When I create the headers using the `Headers` object, headers are dropped out. This is the case even if I am using the `set` or `append` method to fill headers.
Using `new Headers({...});` as it is stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44959749/fetch-with-headers) does not solve the issue. Changing the `mode` also produces no change.
Folowing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43724668/javascript-fetch-api-header-params-not-working/43725133) also fails.

[Link to the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/074au8d6/2/)

As a result, no headers (and no body I guess) are defined.

[image]

[image]

If somebody has an idea about the issue, I'll take it :D

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `mode: 'no-cors'` you are restricted to [simple headers](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#simple-header)

- accept
- accept-language
- content-language
- content-type

That's all the headers you are allowed in no-cors mode

source: [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/mode#Syntax)

below, the first request is made mode no-cors and the second mode same-origin (though, this could also be cors and would work the same)

```js
// Code goes here

function createRequest(type, url, payload, corsmode) {
  const options = {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "x-request-id": '...',
      "x-sender-id": "mysender"
    },
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(payload),
    mode: corsmode,
    cache: 'no-cache'
  };
  return new Request(url, options);
}

// -----------------------------
// a simple test
const request = createRequest('post', '/check', {
  test: 'where are my headers?'
}, 'no-cors');


console.log([...request.headers.entries()]);

const request2 = createRequest('post', '/check', {
  test: 'where are my headers?'
}, 'same-origin');

console.log([...request2.headers.entries()]);
```

Comment: @ollie314 - I've added a code snippet to show the difference and to show how you can log the headers to the console